# Integral of simple algebraic function

Tags: integration, substitution, rational-functions, reduction-formula

I want to find an analytic expression for the following integral $$\int_{x_+}^Xdx\left(\frac{a}{x-b}+\frac{a^*}{x-b^*}\right)\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-x_-)(x-x_+)}}\,,\quad a,b\in\mathbb{C}\,,\quad x_\pm\in\mathbb{R}\,,\quad x_+>x_-\,.$$
I know that an analytic expression in terms of elementary functions exists because Mathematica can give me one. The problem is that it is hideously and unnecessarily complicated, hence I want to evaluate it by hand. There is a formula for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, but not for complex $a,b$. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use $Euler\ Sub\ldots$. Namely,
$$
x = {x_{+}x_{-}\ -\ t^{2} \over 2t\ +\ x_{+}\ +\ x_{-}}
$$
It yields simple integrals.

Comment: @FelixMarin Thanks, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

For
$$\int \frac {dx}{(x-a)\sqrt{(x-b)(x-c)}}$$
$$x=\frac{c (a-b)+b  (a-c) t^2} {(a-b)+ (a-c)t^2 }\implies dx=\frac{2  (a-b) (a-c) (b-c)\,t}{\big[(a-b)+ (a-c)t^2\big]^2}\,dt$$ makes also the antiderivative more than simple.

Comment: Since $a$ is complex in this case, your substitution will turn the integral into a contour integral in the complex plane, which I don't know how to evaluate. The residue theorem is not very useful because the upper limit is not infinity but some finite $X$.

Comment: @BlindMiner The problem with democarcy is that I may disagree (joke). You should end with arctangent and hyperbolic arctangent may be with complex arguments.